# ConnectionFactory throwing errors when shared

Tags: activemq-artemis

I've a very simple application that adds messages to a queue and reads them using a MessagerListener.

Edit: I was testing this on a single instance of Artemis that had been setup as part of a two instance cluster on docker.

I want to create the ConnectionFactory once and reuse it for all producers and consumers in the application.
I have created the ConnectionFactory and stored it in a static variable (singleton) so it can be accessed from anywhere.
The aim is that the client use this shared connection factory to create a new connection when required.
However, I have noticed that doing this causes a "Failed to create session factory" when trying to create a new connection.

```
javax.jms.JMSException: Failed to create session factory
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createConnectionInternal(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:886)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:299)
    at com.test.artemistest.jms.QueueTest2.getMessagesFromQueue(QueueTest2.java:137)
    at com.test.artemistest.jms.QueueTest2.access$000(QueueTest2.java:61)
    at com.test.artemistest.jms.QueueTest2$1.run(QueueTest2.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)
Caused by: ActiveMQNotConnectedException[errorType=NOT_CONNECTED message=AMQ219007: Cannot connect to server(s). Tried with all available servers.]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ServerLocatorImpl.createSessionFactory(ServerLocatorImpl.java:690)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createConnectionInternal(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:884)
```

If I create a connection factory per call this error does not occur.
Doing this seems very inefficient.

I've recreated a similar issue below.
If I create the connection factory in the main method the error occurs.
However if created just before use in a method it works as expected.

If I add two listeners the error occurs even though they are in separate threads. Could it be linked to the fact the connections are not closed in the consumers but are in the producers?

Why is this the case and do you recommend sharing the connection factory?

Thanks

```
public class QueueTest2 {

    private static boolean shutdown = false;

    private static ConnectionFactory cf;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // uncomment below for error to occur
//        QueueTest2.getConnectionFactory("localhost", 61616);
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

        executor.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                getMessagesFromQueue("localhost", 61616);
                while (!shutdown) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000L);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("getMessagesFromQueue shutdown");
            }
        });

        addMessagesToQueue("localhost", 61616);

       // uncommenting below also causes the issue
//        executor.execute(new Runnable() {
//            @Override
//            public void run() {
//                getMessagesFromQueue("localhost", 61616);
//                while (!shutdown) {
//                    try {
//                        Thread.sleep(1000L);
//                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
//                        e.printStackTrace();
//                    }
//                }
//                System.out.println("getMessagesFromQueue shutdown");
//            }
//        });
        

        addMessagesToQueue("localhost", 61616);

        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000L);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        shutdown = true;
        executor.shutdownNow();
    }

    private static void addMessagesToQueue(String host, int port) {

        ConnectionFactory cf2 = getConnectionFactory(host, port);

        Connection connection = null;
        Session sessionQueue = null;

        try {

            connection = cf2.createConnection("artemis", "password");
            connection.setClientID("Producer");

            sessionQueue = connection.createSession(false, Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE);
            Queue orderQueue = sessionQueue.createQueue("exampleQueue");
            MessageProducer producerQueue = sessionQueue.createProducer(orderQueue);
            connection.start();

            // send 100 messages
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                TextMessage message = sessionQueue.createTextMessage("This is an order: " + i);
                producerQueue.send(message);
            }

        } catch (JMSException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(QueueTest2.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } finally {
            try {
                if (sessionQueue != null) {
                    sessionQueue.close();
                }
            } catch (JMSException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(QueueTest2.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            try {
                if (connection != null) {
                    connection.close();
                }
            } catch (JMSException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(QueueTest2.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }

    }

    private static void getMessagesFromQueue(String host, int port) {
        ConnectionFactory cf2 = getConnectionFactory(host, port);
        Connection connection2 = null;

        Session sessionQueue2;

        try {

            connection2 = cf2.createConnection("artemis", "password");
            connection2.setClientID("Consumer2");

            sessionQueue2 = connection2.createSession(false, Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE);
            Queue orderQueue = sessionQueue2.createQueue("exampleQueue");

            MessageConsumer consumerQueue = sessionQueue2.createConsumer(orderQueue);
            consumerQueue.setMessageListener(new MessageHandlerTest2());

            connection2.start();

            Thread.sleep(5000);

        } catch (JMSException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(QueueTest2.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(QueueTest2.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }

    private static ConnectionFactory getConnectionFactory(String host, int port) {
        if (cf == null) {
            Map<String, Object> connectionParams2 = new HashMap<String, Object>();

            connectionParams2.put(TransportConstants.PORT_PROP_NAME, port);
            connectionParams2.put(TransportConstants.HOST_PROP_NAME, host);
            TransportConfiguration transportConfiguration = new TransportConfiguration(NettyConnectorFactory.class
                    .getName(), connectionParams2);
            cf = ActiveMQJMSClient.createConnectionFactoryWithoutHA(JMSFactoryType.CF, transportConfiguration);
        }
        return cf;
    }

}

class MessageHandlerTest2 implements MessageListener {

    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message message) {
        try {
            System.out.println("new message: " + ((TextMessage) message).getText());

            message.acknowledge();
        } catch (JMSException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MessageHandlerTest2.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution that works on a clustered environment and docker.
It involves using the "[pooled-jms](https://github.com/messaginghub/pooled-jms)" connection pool. Something I had planned to use anyway.

Although it does not explain the issues I was seeing above, it is at least a work around until I can investigate further.

The "WARN: AMQ212064: Unable to receive cluster topology " mentioned above appears to have been a red herring as it went away as quickly as it appeared.

Answer (score 0):

I've run your code, but I don't see any errors. My guess is that there may be a timing issue related to concurrency. Try adding `synchronized` to your `getConnectionFactory` method since it can theoretically be called concurrently by multiple threads in your application, e.g.:

```java
private synchronized static ConnectionFactory getConnectionFactory(String host, int port)
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately this is not the issue. It does seem to be a problem with clustering though. I was testing it on a single docker instance that had been set up as one of a pair for clustering (other instance had been disabled). Once I run it on a clean non clustered docker instance it works as expected.   When I ran the above code today on the original clustered instances I started seeing the following error "WARN: AMQ212064: Unable to receive cluster topology ". Go figure as to why that's showing now. Anyway back to clustering on docker which seems to be a bit of a nightmare....

Comment: You should update your question with these details. If clustering is required to reproduce the issue that's an important detail which should be clearly noted.

Comment: Also, I recommend you reproduce the issue without docker (i.e. just running the cluster on `localhost` using different ports. Simplifying the environment is always wise when attempting to isolate a problem.